# .NET Core - Is DateTime Ticks value calculated differently on Windows and Linux platforms?

Tags: .net, linux, windows, .net-core

I've run in to an unexpected behavior while running some tests involving time zones.

Running the below test via XUnit and my IDE (Rider) on Windows, I get different Ticks values for the local and UTC dates below.

When I run the below test on Ubuntu WSL (as part of a Docker build), the values are the same. And so for the following test to pass on both platforms, I have to include a check for the Windows OS.

Both my local Windows and the Ubuntu WSL instance are configured for the local timezone (London/Europe, in BST at the time of writing).

Are ticks calculated differently for .NET DateTimes on Windows and Linux platforms?

According to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/fde7e5b0-e2b9-4d3b-8a63-c2ae75e316d8

> DateTime.Ticks is documented as "number of 100-nanosecond intervals
> that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001".  That is
> 1-Jan-0001 local time.  If you convert your DateTime to UTC, Ticks
> will then be number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed
> since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 UTC.  Potentially different
> that 1-Jan-0001 local time, ergo the two Ticks values will be
> different.

... but under Ubuntu WSL the Ticks value is the same.

```
[Fact]
public void TestTimeZoneWindowsLinuxTicksBehaviour()
{
    DateTime compareDateTimeLocal2 = new DateTime(2001, 08, 01, 06, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);

    DateTime compareDateTimeUtc2 = compareDateTimeLocal2.ToUniversalTime();

    bool isWindows = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows);

    if (isWindows)
    {
        Assert.NotEqual(compareDateTimeLocal2.Ticks, compareDateTimeUtc2.Ticks);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Equal(compareDateTimeLocal2.Ticks, compareDateTimeUtc2.Ticks);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the timezone offset of Ubuntu? I suspect it's UTC

Comment: On MacOS the two values differ by the expected amount

Comment: Timezone offset on Unbuntu is (UTC +01:00) from `$ date +"%Z %z"` returns `BST +0100`